# Is there a Rack or Sinatra based environment configuration utility?

Tags: ruby, deployment, development-environment, sinatra, rack

Is there anything in the Sinatra / Rack world similar to Rails configuration loading scheme that loads one of the `config\enviroments\*.rb` files depending on `Rails.env`

I know I could develop one pretty easily, i was just wondering if there was something already in place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that **there is something from Sinatra**, that provides a similar, though limited, functionality.

See the code:
https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L1120

So that you can do this:

```
class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
  configure :development, :test do
    #only executes this code when environment is equal to one of the passed arguments
    # I'm pretty sure Sinatra sets this based on ENV['RACK_ENV']
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're following the Rails convention of putting a file for each environment in config/environments/environment_name.rb, you can put something like this in your Sinatra app, or for Rack in your config.ru file:

```
Dir.glob(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/config/environments/#{settings.environment}.rb", &method(:require))
```

With some minor modifications you could make it load other file locations/combinations. Sinatra's configure blocks work just as well, too.

Comment: Thanks, thats pretty much what I ended up doing.. except I just let it fail if the env file doesn't exist: `require "config/#{settings.environment}"`

Answer (score 3):

There is one called Sinatra::ConfigFile, which now lives in Sinatra::Contrib http://www.sinatrarb.com/contrib/config_file.html

There's lots of useful stuff in there.

Answer (score 1):

I adapted mine from monkrb.com (it's also yaml in RoR anyways)

```
YAML.load_file(path_of "config/settings.yml")[RACK_ENV]
```

e.g.
http://github.com/codepants/yasumi/blob/master/config/settings.yml